# How do I put the result of subtracting the values of two registers into a third register using Assembly?

Tags: assembly

I just started learning a little assembly and I'm a bit stuck. Lets say I'm putting two values into registers A&B like so:

```
MOV A, 45d
MOV B, 127d
```

What I'm trying to do is subtract those values and put the result into register C. I've tried doing the following:

```
diff: SUB B, A

MOV C, diff
```

I read that SUB will take the result of the operation and put it in the destination (B), but I just don't know how to move it into register C.

EDIT: I think I've got it. I went ahead and did the following:

```
MOV A, 26d
MOV B, 193d

MOV C, B

SUB C, A
```

Comment: Once you have the result in B, you can move it into C: `MOV C, B`. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: On what architecture? Some architectures support three operands like `SUB C, B, A` meaning "subtract A from B and store the result in C".

Comment: zx485, I'm using this website: https://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/index.html

Answer (score 1):

A 3-operand ISA like RISC-V or AArch64 can `sub dst, src1, src2` non-destructively.
e.g. `sub x1, x2, x3` happens to be valid for both ISAs, as they both have registers x0..31.

A 2-operand ISA can emulate that with `mov dst, src1` / `sub dst, src2`.  Same for any other 2-input operation where you want the result in a 3rd register without modifying either input.

Some ISAs may have restrictions on which instructions can use which registers, e.g. x86 before 386 could only [multiply two registers](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul) if one of them was the accumulator, and the destination was implicitly DX:AX (16x16 => 32-bit) or AX (8x8 => 16-bit).  But if you have a simple orthogonal 2-operand ISA where each instruction can use any two registers, this isn't a problem.

`diff: SUB B, A` / `MOV C, diff` would load C with the address of that label, or load the machine-code bytes from that address.  Definitely not copy the subtraction result from the `B` register.